# Can a static shock to a motherboard damage a hard drive that is connected?

Tags: esd, motherboard, static-electricity

Hypothetically, could the shock spread through the board and follow the wires and damage a hard drive?

Comment: Only a fool would say it's impossible. It rather depends on the protection of the board, the drive, the energy of the discharge, and how it was applied to the board.

Comment: electricity can indeed spread through wires, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically yes, a static discharge can reach few thousand volts and can reach everywhere inside a PC. Practically, modern day SATA drives have ESD protection devices on their inputs, so an ESD strike on the motherboard shouldn't fry the hard drive.

Comment: A few thousand volts?  Polyester pants/dress with rubber sole shoes on a carpet can **easily** reach over **100k volts**!

Comment: I was being cautious, and assume that anyone working on a PC would have an antistatic strap (and not the wireless one...).

Comment: @Aaron which is why all my work clothes are 100% cotton   ;)

Comment: @LiorBilia what do you mean by `the wireless one`?

Comment: @KyleB jeans and a cotton t-shirt ... lol

Comment: This scam (Thanks BigClive) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4-rO70_h0ck